# Joining on derived column without using subquery

Tags: mysql, join, view, subquery, derived

In MySQL I'm trying to join two tables on a derived column, something like this:

```
SELECT C.country, 
  IFNULL(C.preferred_city, C.default_city) AS best_city,
  PC.postal_code
FROM Countries as C
INNER JOIN PostalCodes AS PC
ON best_city=PC.city
```

This of course does not work because `best_city` is outside the scope of the `ON` clause.

The only solution I could find was using a subquery (or is this considered a derived table? I'm fuzzy on the nomenclature):

```
SELECT BC.*, PC.postal_code
FROM (
  SELECT country, IFNULL(preferred_city, default_city) AS best_city
  FROM COUNTRIES
) AS BC
INNER JOIN PostalCodes AS PC
ON BC.best_city=PC.city
```

which works nicely from the shell.  However, I'm trying to implement this as a view and it gives me the error:  *ERROR 1349: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause*

How can I rework this to join without using a subquery??

Thanks!

Comment: You can use expressions in the `JOIN` predicate:  `FROM Countries AS C JOIN PostalCodes AS PC ON IFNULL(C.preferred_city, C.default_city) = PC.city`—however be aware that this is not sargable.

Comment: You could place your subquery in a view and then just join to that view. Ugly, but it'd get around MySQL limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT BC.*, PC.postal_code
FROM COUNTRIES BC
INNER JOIN PostalCodes AS PC
ON PC.city = IFNULL(preferred_city, default_city)
```